# getLastLocation does not work on second time

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I'm using google play services to get user's last known connection.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {


  final Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                _googleApiClient);
}

 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        connectToGooglePlay();   
    }

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (_googleApiClient != null) {
            _googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Works as expected.

The problem occurs whenever I'm clicking on back button and then starting the application again. My app crashes because `getLastLocation` return null. The formal documentation states -

> If a location is not available, which should happen very rarely, null
>   will be returned.

Fine, however I know for sure that a location exists, I just retrieved it a second ago.

I did a quick experiment and removed `_googleApiClient.disconnect();` and it works, somehow the disconnect erases the last location

Why ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Why do you disconnect? Have you tried removing that?

Comment: @CodyHarness that's what I wrote, I removed disconnect and it works, however according to the formal documentation it's recommended to disconnect in onStop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

I'm using roboguice for injection.

Instead of creating a new GoogleApiClient.Builder each time, I used a singleton to create it only once, it looks like when calling disconnect it ruins the state of the builder.

The solution - I'm creating a new builder each time I need to create a GoogleApiClient

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

1) You should connect to `GoogleApiClient` in `onStart()` and disconnect in 
`onStop()`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

2) Your code should always assume that `getLastLocation()` may return `null`. Do a null check.

3) Use `isLocationAvailable()` when working with `getLastLocation()`.  If it returns true, then the location returned by `getLastLocation()` can be assumed to be reasonably up to date.

Comment: where does getLastLocation() gets location coordinates from?